# Add a new row for each jsonb value pairs

Tags: select, postgresql-13

I have this table from were I'm running a query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.preprocess_things
(
    preprocess_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('preprocess_things_preprocess_id_seq'::regclass),
    arrive_date date NOT NULL,
    arrive_location character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    data jsonb NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT preprocess_things_pkey PRIMARY KEY (preprocess_id),
    CONSTRAINT preprocess_things_arrive_date_arrive_location_bo_key UNIQUE (arrive_date, arrive_location)
)
```

The query that I'm running is this:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', arrive_date) AS grouped_date,
  LOWER(arrive_location) AS location,
  json_build_object(
    '1', SUM((data->'1')::int),
    '2', SUM((data->'2')::int),
    '3', SUM((data->'3')::int),
    '4', SUM((data->'4')::int),
    '5', SUM((data->'5')::int)
    ) AS data
FROM preprocess_things
GROUP BY grouped_date,
  location
```

The current result is:

| grouped_date | location | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-06-01 00:00:00 | location_00 | {"1" : 1, "2" : null, "3" : null, "4" : 1, "5" : 8} |
| 2018-05-01 00:00:00 | location_00 | {"1" : null, "2" : 9, "3" : 10, "4" : 8, "5" : 3} |

I would like to apply another SELECT, that adds a row for each value pair that does not have a null value, where the key goes to the thing_type column and the value goes to the total column; like this:

| grouped_date | location | thing_type | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-06-01 00:00:00 | location_00 | 1 | 1 |
| 2018-06-01 00:00:00 | location_00 | 4 | 1 |
| 2018-06-01 00:00:00 | location_00 | 5 | 8 |
| 2018-05-01 00:00:00 | location_00 | 2 | 9 |
| 2018-05-01 00:00:00 | location_00 | 3 | 10 |
| 2018-05-01 00:00:00 | location_00 | 4 | 8 |
| 2018-05-01 00:00:00 | location_00 | 5 | 3 |

The fiddle db can be found [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6524fe338ae6bde54fe9bd100e11c785).

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to [@Gerard H. Pille](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/143823/gerard-h-pille), I tweak a little bit he's response to this:

```
SELECT
  DATE_TRUNC('month', arrive_date) AS grouped_date,
  LOWER(arrive_location) AS location,
  x.key::int thing_type, sum(x.value::int) total
FROM preprocess_things
JOIN  jsonb_each(data) x ON (x.key::int = ANY('{1,2,3}'::int[]))
GROUP BY grouped_date,  location, x.key::int
ORDER BY grouped_date,  location, x.key::int;
```

Since there are some cases were I just need a selection of the thing_type and not all of them to be calculated, the only problem is by adding the JOIN and compare the query speed is not that good.

Comment: `ON x.key IN ('1','2','3')` maybe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  DATE_TRUNC('month', arrive_date) AS grouped_date,
  LOWER(arrive_location) AS location,
  x.key::int  thing_type, sum(x.value::int) total
    FROM preprocess_things,
         jsonb_each(data) x
  GROUP BY grouped_date,  location, x.key::int
  order by grouped_date,  location, x.key::int;
```

see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=30dcd885d5581ab83c8f23602cba4b9c)